# Early 2000s series with police unit catching supernatural creatures. Main character reveals invisible monster in an episode and says "nice to see you"

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a live action TV series; I think from the early 2000s.

The story was about a special police unit force, which was tasked to capture supernatural creatures. The creatures were mostly related to folklores, but some of them were just plain sci-fi monsters too, such as: sandman, bogeyman, vampires, cupid, grease monster, etc.

The two main casts were a man with short black hair, and a woman with long blonde hair. Sometimes, they would be followed by a 3rd guy who was a gnome (who was said to have a skin impervious to damage; only diamond could damage him or something).

Within the organisation for which they work, two of the recurring characters were: the chief, who was black with very short grey hair, and the cliché computer geek who was the contact for any information or forensic (although he did not wear any glass, as far as I can remember).

Some episodes I remember:

- The very first episode I remember had a woman looking into the toilet before getting attacked by a monster made of grease coming out of it. At the very end, I think the two main characters defeated it by melting it, using some kind of special weapons. The forensic guy then turned the remain of the monster into bouncing balls for the two main casts (although it's made of grease instead of rubber).
- In one episode, they were trying to capture some kind of invisible creature, which only a young child could see; maybe the bogeyman? At the very end, the main guy was trying to fight it by listening to the child telling him where it is. At some point, the monster grabbed a can with some kind of gas, so the guy shot at the can. Its content sprayed the monster, and it was no longer invisible. They stared each other for some time, until the main guy told him as a form of pun: *"nice to see you"*.
- In another episode, there was some kind of sandman monster who was possessing people who fell asleep. At some point in that episode, the main female character fell asleep and he possessed her. In order to defeat him, they had him climb into a helicopter (as the possessed woman) along with the main guy. For some reasons, the main guy lost consciousness, so the sandman left the woman and tried to grab a parachute to escape. Unfortunately for him, the parachute was rigged, so it did not activate when he pulled, and he fell into the water to his death.
- One episode had a TV show for kids in which a guy was wearing a blue costume to entertain the children, and he was playing the melodica. I think the idea was that he was brainwashing the children into being his slaves, which he used to rob jewellery. At some point, it was revealed the melodica was a decoy, because it's an empty instrument, and the music was coming straight from his vocal chords. They tried to use a rigged microphone to counteract his brainwashing, but since it's failed, the main character shot some helium balloons, which messed up the guy's voice, freeing the children from his brainwashing.
- In an episode I barely remember, the three main casts (the guy, the woman and the gnome) were interviewing people as they were leaving a building I think. For some reasons, the gnome suddenly picked a guy wearing a baseball cap, asking him to read some kind of slur on a piece of paper, but the guy couldn't. When the gnome asked the guy to remove his cap, he tried to run away, so the two other main casts stopped him and forcefully removed his cap. It's then revealed that he had a third eye on the forehead, after which he told the gnome that he'll make him pay one day.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*[Special Unit 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Unit_2)*

> "Links" are the common monsters from folklore and mythology (except vampires, whose existence is specifically identified as preposterous), and are described as being the missing link between apes and humans (although other human-like species have evolved, for instance gargoyles, who are identified as humanoid descendants of dinosaurs). They live in hiding and/or disguise among the human population. On occasions when Links are seen by humans, they are usually dismissed as hallucinations or optical illusions, except by those who are especially perceptive. Special Unit 2 is the top-secret division of the Chicago police specifically designated to handle Link-related cases. Other units of the police department are specifically ordered to stay out of Special Unit 2's way, which provides a great deal of leeway and access for cases.
>
> Detective Nick O'Malley (Michael Landes) and his newly assigned partner, Detective Kate Benson (Alexondra Lee), are the two central characters. Nick is a maverick veteran in Special Unit 2. His initially callous, jaded and at times cruel demeanor is revealed to be a result of guilt over the loss of his previous partner; Julie. A criminal called The Chameleon cut her up into "600 inch-sized cubes". (It would later be revealed that Nick and Julie were having a secret affair.) Kate is one of the rare individuals who acknowledge the existence of Links instead of finding a more acceptable (albeit incorrect) explanation for the traditionally unexplained phenomena that they cause. Her refusal to deny her observations jeopardizes her career as a police officer and estranges her from her fellow officers. Kate's tenacity and conviction leads to her recruitment by Special Unit 2.
>
> Supporting characters include Captain Richard Page (Richard Gant), SU2's commanding officer with a prosthetic metal hand that serves as the focus of running gags. The unit's liaison with the Link community is Carl (Danny Woodburn), a verbally aggressive gnome known for kleptomania and armed robbery, who is mutually antagonistic towards Nick. Nick and Carl's love-hate relationship contributes some of the humor within the fantasy universe of the show. Carl is completely invincible to everything but a diamond-coated saw and dragon fire/teeth.

## Trailer

- Episode 5, "The Waste", involves a monster made from liposuction fat, the first victim is attacked by a hand coming out the toilet, and indeed the lab guy makes bouncy balls out of him after he's killed.
- Episode 10, "The Invisible" involves a bogeyman only able to be seen by children. Indeed, he's revealed by a spray invented by the lab guy, and O'Malley says "Nice to see you" before opening fire.
- Episode 7, "The Grain" has the sandman who is defeated by jumping out of the helicopter with a faulty parachute. It also has, earlier on, the scene where Carl singles out a boy with a ball-cap, asking him to read the text on a piece of paper ("EXIT", rather than a slur) and he's unable to do so, whereupon they remove his hat and reveal that he has two eyes on his forehead.
- Episode 18, "The Piper" has the mind controlling child performer.

Found with a search for `tv series police supernatural creatures`

Comment: Wow, I'm actually surprised it was found with such simple keywords. I think I'm going to try simpler search terms next time.

Comment: Sometimes, I get lucky. :-D

Comment: @Clockwork Your caption was accurate enough for me to instantly check whether SU2 was mentioned already. Was such an interesting and memorable show IMO.

Comment: _[Nice to see you](https://youtu.be/GartviKneP8?t=2439)_

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - now I can raise my nose up and feel all superior, as I knew the asnwer without even a google search :P  (being a fan of the series :")   Good research, though :)

Comment: I found the one with the baseball cap guy. It's in the sandman episode: https://youtu.be/6SM96Bn_p6g?t=1543

Comment: "remove his hate" => I suppose you meant "hat"? And... would he be unable to "read" (not "reach") the text?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks. I was editing on the road, and it looked like my phone autocorrected some of my words.